# How can I extract the array of hashmap object from a hashmap object?

Tags: java, json

```
{
    "errorCode": 200,
    "opMessage": {
        "personalDetails": {
            "dob": {
                "mm": 2,
                "dd": 2,
                "yyyy": 1975
            },
            "name": {
                "fname": "sai gampa",
                "lName": "krishna"
            },
            "maritalStatus": "Single",
            "ssn": "123-45-7777"
        },
        "id": "0101",
        "contactDetails": {
            "address": [
                {
                    "isPrimary": true,
                    "id": "HOME;2017-06-30",
                    "type": "Home",
                    "addr": {
                        "country": "USA",
                        "addr2": "W 24th St",
                        "addr1": "518",
                        "city": "New York",
                        "postalCode": "11122",
                        "state": "NY"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "isPrimary": false,
                    "id": "BUSN;2017-07-04",
                    "type": "Work",
                    "addr": {
                        "country": "USA",
                        "addr2": "Agsuaiajs",
                        "addr1": "Qwertyy",
                        "city": "Shshshsjsj",
                        "postalCode": "71899",
                        "state": "CO"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "bestWayToContact": "Phone",
            "ph": [
                {
                    "isPrimary": false,
                    "num": "666-666-6666",
                    "id": "Work",
                    "type": "Work"
                },
                {
                    "isPrimary": false,
                    "num": "444-444-4444",
                    "id": "Cell",
                    "type": "Cell"
                },
                {
                    "isPrimary": true,
                    "num": "111-111-1111",
                    "id": "Home",
                    "type": "Home"
                }
            ],
            "eMail": [
                {
                    "isPrimary": true,
                    "id": "HOME",
                    "addr": "Shyam@gmail.con"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Lets say I want to extract eMail array of objects

Comment: please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44924419/edit) don't comment

Comment: Just deserialize it using a json deserializer. There are plenty of examples around the net.

Answer (score 0):

HashMap has a method called entrySet(). With entrySet() you can get all the entries in the hashmap.

Comment: I'm not into coding. can you just mention the code that I should write to extract the email array